# Why isn't this centering?

Tags: html, css

I can't get this to center. I've tried adding aligns everywhere, and every different combination of  tags. I know the HTML isn't great... but I'm just trying to get something functional right now - not worrying about best practices.

```
<table class='navbar' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td class='navbar'>
            <a href='#' class='cta cta-big cta-red'><center><span class='icon-go'>No</span></a></center>
        </td>
        <td class='navbar'>
            <center><a href='#' class='cta cta-big cta-yellow'><span class='icon-download'>Maybe</span></a></center>
        </td>
        <td class='navbar'>
            <center><a href='#' class='cta cta-big cta-green'><span class='icon-check'>Yes</span></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

These answers show there are different kinds of "centering" in CSS, let's call these two text centering and block centering. The 'text-align' property governs where lines of text flush up, right, left, center, justified (right and left with extra padding between the words to make them flush up). This is what usually is thought of as "centering", and what you can see as icons in WYSIWYG text editing.

When you do layout you often have another centering task, you want one box to be in the center of another box. By the CSS way of thinking this is the box model (almost everything is a box to CSS), and you can reformulate "center this box inside that box" into "make sure that the left margin and the right margin of the inner box are the same". For instance if the outer box is 200 pixels wide, and the inner box is 120 pixels wide, you want the left margin = right margin, or in other words each margin will have to be 40 pixels. (40+120+40 = 200).

Hard-coding this is a lot of calculation, and it will break if either box changes size. Fortunately we have the margin: auto value which does it for us (it does "OK, this box is 120 pixels wide, we have room for 200 pixels, then I'll split the extra 80 in half and give it to each margin"), and it will keep working even when the layout (and box sizes) change.

Finally we have vertical alignment. CSS doesn't do that satisfactory yet, but there is a trick. See http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center for more on this.

Oh, and the HTML 'center' element mixed those two above models, but it didn't do it very well. I would advise you to stay away from the center tag (besides it is a good idea to keep style apart from markup).

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the `<center>` tags:

```
<table class='navbar' width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td class='navbar'>
            <a href='#' class='cta cta-big cta-red'><span class='icon-go'>No</span></a>
       </td>
        <td class='navbar'>
            <a href='#' class='cta cta-big cta-yellow'><span class='icon-download'>Maybe</span></a>
        </td>
        <td class='navbar'>
            <a href='#' class='cta cta-big cta-green'><span class='icon-check'>Yes</span></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And use CSS to do the centering:

```
table {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w7rWx/

"Not worrying about best practices" is often a difficult way to "get something functional", especially cross-browser. It's in your best interest to at least make an effort, consider adopting a different approach towards HTML/CSS.

Comment: +1 for saying "Get rid of the `<center>` tags". Those are so outdated!

Comment: `<center>` as been [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/center) for a long time, and for good reason - but browsers will still abide by its behavior (for now at least). I suspect the table layout here is not necessary either. Kris, if you explain your requirements for what you want it to look like, I'd be happy to rewrite this for you in a clean way, it might be a good way to learn by example.

Comment: That's appreciated, especially since all the methods posted so far haven't seemed to work. I'm not sure if something in my CSS file is making it break - without the formatting it works on fiddle, but when I add everything in on the code itself, it just right-aligns everything again.

Is there a way to contact you on this? I looked around but couldn't find a feature.

Comment: Yeah sure, just edit your post. Provide your code, note the formatting tools (4 spaces to indent), [make a demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and state clearly what it is you want to happen. As Jonny Axelsson said, the concept of "centering" has many meanings. Anyone available will help, you don't need to contact members here personally.

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w7rWx/1/

The CSS is from Pixify, but I'm not sure why I can't get those buttons to center. They're beautiful, but regardless of what I try, the buttons always align to the left. The table code is probably irrelevant now - I've taken your suggestions, and I'm playing around with twitter bootstrap now. Thank you!

Comment: Well, this is a different case altogether - there are supposed to be icons in the buttons, that's why it's not centered. If the icons were there it would look fine. Try adding this and tell me if you get what you want: `.navbar .cta span {padding:0;} .navbar .cta{float:none}` Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w7rWx/3/ - In the future though, please edit you post instead of hiding details in the comments, so everyone can read it. I should have done the same.

Comment: I tried what you suggested with the icon, but then the icon stacks. Is there an easy way to fix this? I'll edit my post when it's resolved so it makes more sense if that's okay!

http://i56.tinypic.com/2wh07xc.png

Comment: Oh, then if you *do* have the icons, remove `.navbar .cta span {padding:0;}` from what I said earlier. http://jsfiddle.net/w7rWx/4/ Yeah, definitely edit your post with this stuff, or maybe even make a new one - this post doesn't really represent what you're actually trying to do here anymore and you have a lot of answers that address a different question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this css.

```
.center {
     float: none;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 0;
     position: relative;
}
```

`margin: 0 auto;` does the trick of centering. BTW, mentioning the width attribute also will make sure that the right and left margins depending on the window size.

Comment: I'm sorry - how do I use that? I put it into my css file, but where should I reference it?

Comment: @Kris you can change '.center' to '.navbar' so the changes will be automatically done once you put the code in the css file.

Comment: @sdle - No it doesn't. And is the why I mentioned it as a note.

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` only works on fixed width block level elements.

Answer (score 0):

In the first `<td>`, you have your HTML organized like so:

```
<a><center><span></span></a></center>
```

You're closing the tags in the wrong order; from the other two lines, it looks like you meant to do:

```
<center><a><span></span></a></center>
```

And in the third `<td>`, you didn't close the `<center>` at all.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqjym/) with those changes made, and it looks like it works.

Answer (score 0):

As already said: get rid of the center tag…

As for code Wesley Murch already gave you a very good answer though it will apply to all your table. I you want your style to apply only to a few elements try this:

```
.center{
    text-align:center;
}
```

And apply it to "td" element by writing:

```
<td class='navbar center'>
        <a href='#' class='cta cta-big cta-green'><span class='icon-check'>Yes</span></a>
</td>
```